# HIVE_30 - Invalid column name

Tags: streamsets

I am trying to load zip file to hive database using streamsets pipeline getting the below error.

Error: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.OnRecordErrorException: HIVE_30 - Invalid column name remarks stress at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.hive.HiveMetadataProcessor.process(HiveMetadataProcessor.java:594) at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.RecordProcessor.process(RecordProcessor.java:52)

Configured compressed format = archive and with header line

I found the issue is source csv file column having spaces beetween

Ex : Strem sets please suggest how to add "_" instead of spaces from the source column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Field Mapper](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Processors/FieldMapper.html#concept_q5y_tdq_xgb) to rename the field:

[image]